# How can I safely increase gluteal load in the bulgarian squat?

Tags: squats, bodyweight-exercises, form, technique

[In this video](https://youtu.be/2C-uNgKwPLE?t=1m52s) it is stated that lengthening the foot stance increases gluteal load. However, this also forces a flatter back angle, when a lot of people say that it's important to keep your back upright when doing bulgarian squats.

Is increasing stance length and leaning a bit more forward a good way to increase gluteal load without introducing weights, or are there better ways to do this? Or should I just look for a different exercise to train glutes?

Comment: you did not provide the link to the video ?